# Peer reviewed guides for the Philosophy of Religion

Tags: philosophy-of-religion

I'm searching for good journals that you can write for. Specializing in the Philosophy of Religion. Has there been any members here on SE which have written for these types of journals? What is the potential pitfalls you may encounter and is writing of this sort really worth the time and effort?

Comment: Do you mean proper academic journals or something more approachable to the layman (that you could realistically "write for")? E.g., proper journal: *Faith and Philosophy* ; accessible to layman level: *Relevant Magazine* ?

Comment: the latter virmaior

Comment: With the comments, it sounds like the question is asking for *non*-academic publications -- which sounded sort of strange when I was trying to rewrite the headline as a question. Maybe it's something like: "What are some peer-reviewed but accessible publications specializing in philosophy of religion?"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can write for Faith and Philosophy in the form of a book review to get started. I did this in grad school. Or you can work to get accepted in a PhD program specializing in philosophy of religion, and while you are there, you can work up seminar papers into publishable pieces in the International Journal for the Philosophy of Religion, Religious Studies, or maybe another journal I am forgetting. My graduate student collegues did this. It took a lot of help from an eminent philosopher to do this though. Hope this helps some.

Comment: But note the comments on the question, the OP is looking for something shy of a proper academic journal.